# Print multiple datagridview pages

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'd like to print my `DataGridView` content, but when I have many rows in this `DataGridView` I don't know how need I use the `HasMorePages` property.

This is my current code:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow sor in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn oszlop in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            szelesseg += oszlop.Width;

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Brown, szelesseg, magassag, oszlop.Width, sor.Height);

            szelesseg_lista.Add(szelesseg);
            magassag_lista.Add(magassag);
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cella in sor.Cells)
        {
            ertekek.Add(cella.Value.ToString());
        }

        szelesseg = 10;
        magassag = magassag + sor.Height;

        cella_magassag += sor.Height;

    }


    int sor_db = ertekek.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < sor_db; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ertekek[i], new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 12, FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), szelesseg_lista[i], magassag_lista[i]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PrintPage event is for every *page* you want to print.  That means your For...Each loop won't work since you are telling the printer to print everything on the current page.

You have to have a variable outside the PrintPage method scope to keep track of which row index you are currently on:

```
int printIndex;

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {

  int y = 0;

  while (printIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count && 
         y + dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Height < e.MarginBounds.Height) {

    // print your stuff, y is where you are on the page vertically

    y += dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Height;
    ++printIndex;
  }

  e.HasMorePages = printIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
}
```

Use the BeginPrint event to reset your printIndex value:

```
private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e) {
  printIndex = 0;
}
```

If you add another variable, such as `int printPage;`, you can now know which page you are currently printing, too, by incrementing that value in the PrintPage event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

Add this method in to your cs page

```
protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
{
    get
    {
        return new SessionPageStatePersister(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget. It's Windows Forms, not ASP.NET :)

Comment: OK then check this link  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19241/Paging-in-a-DatagridView           May be this link useful for you