# How to Print DataGridView with text in the header and footer?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have written the below code for printing data from DataGridView in windows c#.
But I want to print one image, text in header and footer.

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(this.SalesGridView.Width, this.SalesGridView.Height);
        SalesGridView.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.SalesGridView.Width, this.SalesGridView.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);            
    }

    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
```

Comment: This question is a little broad at the moment. Can you post more code showing the main document you are printing? I assume the code you have already posted is the image you want to try and append. Can you also explain what Printing API you are using? The less that people have to guess about, and the more targeted the problem, the more likely you are to get a good answer.

Comment: The code should print the whole DWG, right? If you only want to print parts you will need to write the DrawString and DrawImage methods one by one..

Comment: Actually I am developing an application for grocery shop.
At the time of making bill, I am adding all the items in dataGridiView with item name, purchase quantity, 
ItemPrice and total Price. This dataGridView is field with dataTable.

Actually when any one will print this sales item,
then it will print with header image of shop and some another data like date, etc and footer can also be shop address etc.

Comment: You really shouldn't try to use a Bitmap created from DrawToBitmap. It will have a very low quality and probably all sorts of other problems like backcolors and gridlines etc... Instead you should code the PrintPage event and go through all the motions to print exactly what you want. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368453/c-sharp-preview-print-dialog/28391910#28391910) for a mimimalistic example. You would draw your header and footer and loops through he rows and cell..

Comment: Thanks Taw, You really helped me to do a lot of things, But one thing, suppose I have to give print of two pages and in footer of page want some text like address and contact number. How can I repeat in all pages in bottom, also doing try to show image from local folder but still not success.

Comment: I want to check printing by .xps extension. but my printer was configure to my system. So it always giving printing to my printer. So I removed my printer now it gave message. Error: No Printer are installed. while in web project it shows dialogue box to choose printer. So i am not confirm it is any code error or something else.

Comment: Now i have changed some code now it gives dialog box to choose printers but after choose .xps it again gives error Error; No Printer are installed.

Comment: try
            {

                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();             
                PrintDialog pdi = new PrintDialog();
                pdi.Document = pd;
                pdi.UseEXDialog = true;
                if (pdi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {                    
                    printDocument1.Print();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Your code as is currently conversation your DataGridView to a Bitmap, and then prints that Bitmap. To print text headers and footers in addition to your DataGridView, you need the `Graphics.DrawString()` method:

```
// Create string to draw.
String drawString = "Sample Text";

// Create font and brush.
Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

// Create point for upper-left corner of drawing.
PointF drawPoint = new PointF(150.0F, 150.0F);

// Draw string to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);
}
```

You will have to adjust the float values for the positioning of each graphic. E.g. your code `e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);` prints the Bitmap bm at position (0, 0). So the placement of your header, footer, and DataGridView object positions will need to be changed depending on their size.

If you want to print on multiple pages, [you will need to create a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079360/print-multiple-datagridview-pages) and add your header and footer to each page programmatically.