# C# Preview Print Dialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, printing

I have a datagrid of information and when the print button is clicked
I want to show a print preview screen of what it will look like and then
let the user print the document. Heres what I got so far:

```
        PrintDocument myDocument = new PrintDocument();


        PrintPreviewDialog PrintPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = myDocument;
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

My question is how to get the data onto the preview screen.. thanks!

Comment: Are your problems resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `PrintPage` event:

```
myDocument.DocumentName = "Test2015";
myDocument.PrintPage += myDocument_PrintPage;
```

and you need to code it! In its very simplest form this will dump out the data:

```
void myDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
      foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
      {
          if (Cell.Value != null)
              e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.Value.ToString(), Font,  Brushes.Black, 
                          new Point(cell.ColumnIndex * 123, cell.RowIndex  * 12 ) );
      }
}
```

But of course you will want to add a lot more to get nice formatting etc..

- For example you can use the `Graphics.MeasureString()` method to find out the size of a chunk of text to optimize the coodinates, which are hard coded just for testing here.
- You may use the `cell.FormattedValue` instead of the  raw `Value`.
- You may want to prepare a few `Fonts` you will use, prefix the dgv with a header, maybe a logo..

Also worth considering is to set the `Unit` to something device independent like `mm`:

```
e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
```

And, if need be, you should keep track of the vertical positions so you can add page numbers and recognize when a Page is full!

**Update:** Since your `DGV` may contain empty cells I have added a check for `null`.

Comment: Will the downvoter care to comment? Thanks for __not__ helping to improve SO!

Comment: That is the problem then. I have looked into it; See my answer there!