# Getting printing working

Tags: c#

Currently I am getting a blank page showing up for my print preview.

How can I make it show the data that I have?

Thanks:

Here is what is calling it: it does get called its just that no data shows on the black preview page

```
List<string[]> myList = new List<string[]>();
    myList.Add(new string[] { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" });
    myList.Add(new string[] { "Row 2", "Row 2" });
    myList.Add(new string[] { "Row 3" });
    printUtility.SetUpDocument("TEST", myList);


    public class PrintUtility
    {
        public PrintDocument document;
        public DataGridView dataGridView;



        public PrintUtility()
        {
            document = new PrintDocument();
            dataGridView = new DataGridView();
        }


        public void SetUpDocument(string title, List<string[]> myList)
        {

            document.DocumentName = title;
            document.PrintPage += PrintPage;


            // Convert to DataTable.
            DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(myList);
            this.dataGridView.DataSource = table;

            document.DocumentName = title;
            document.PrintPage += PrintPage;
        }


        public PrintDocument GetDocument()
        {
            return this.document;
        }


        public void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.Value.ToString(), new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black,
                                new Point(cell.ColumnIndex * 123, cell.RowIndex * 12));
                }
        }

        private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<string[]> list)
        {
            // New table.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            // Get max columns.
            int columns = 0;
            foreach (var array in list)
            {
                if (array.Length > columns)
                {
                    columns = array.Length;
                }
            }

            // Add columns.
            for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add();
            }

            // Add rows.
            foreach (var array in list)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(array);
            }

            return table;
        }
}
```

Comment: I see that you are using the code from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368453/c-sharp-preview-print-dialog/28391910#28391910) to your previous question. You really should put a comment there, if you can't get it to work, instead of posting basically the same question, probably with the same problem! - Are there data in the DGV and can you see them in the debugger when you step through the `PrintPage`event??

Comment: Actually I was not quite right; this problem is rather different from the previous post!

Comment: Did you get it to work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are using a DataGridView, that is not really shown anywhere.

But since all you data are in a `DataTable` anyway, why not print from that `DataTable` ? Here is a simple piece of code to replace the loop in the `PrintPage` event:

```
DataTable table = (DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource;

for (int r = 0; r < table.Columns.Count; r++)
{
   DataRow row = table.Rows[r];
   for (int c = 0; c < table.Columns.Count; c++)
   {
     string s = "";
     if (row[c] != null) s = row[c].ToString();
     e.Graphics.DrawString(s, new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 
                   12.0F, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black,  new Point(c * 123, r * 12));
   }
}
```

Again all additional hints from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368453/c-sharp-preview-print-dialog/28391910#28391910) about things to improve the output apply. (Except the `FormattedValue`, which doesn't exist inside a DataTable..)