# Datagridview issue with printing alternate rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hello all I am trying to print data from datagridview in such a way the alternate rows should print left and right. I am able to print but they are not getting in line. Here is the code I tried to print.

Complete code you can find here

**https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByVjmdncQgagRjZvME9STWJoVHc**

```
using (Font font = new Font("Consolas", 13f))
{
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    for (int row = linesPrinted; row < DGV.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
       for (int col = 0; col < DGV.ColumnCount; col++)
       {
          x = 0;
          string text = DGV[col, row].FormattedValue.ToString();
          if (row % 2 == 0)
          {
              x += 10;
              y += 5;
              e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(x, y));
          }
          else
          {
               x += 45;
               y += 5;
               e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(x, y));
          }
      }
}
```

I am getting the output as follows

[image: If you see the right hand side data it] is getting printed after country1 what I need is it should align to top

Comment: start debugging your code..

Comment: I tired in many ways to set by changing the `X` value but still I am not able to make it inline

Comment: Have you tried changing the "Y" value? X is horizontal Y is vertical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appears you are trying to print TWO different rows on the same line, then you are going to have to keep track of where columns 1’s “Y” value starts, this will facilitate lining up column 2. The other issue is the current code simply prints one page when there is more than one page to print.

When looping through the `DataGridView` printing the rows, and we reach the end of the page, we need to call the `PrintPage` method again. In its current form, the `PrintPage` method will start printing from the first row (0) of the `DataGridView` and it will do this for every new page. An infinite loop will ensue because each new page simply starts over with the first row. A global `int` variable `dgvRowIndex` should fix this so that each time the next page is printed we won’t start at the beginning.

I had a difficult time printing multiple pages, however @LarsTech solution worked well at [Print multiple datagridview pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079360/print-multiple-datagridview-pages)

To help, below is a method that simply prints ONE row of the data grid view. The method takes a `rowIndex` to identify which row to use in the `DataGridView`, a `printX` value to indicate the starting left print value, a `printY` value to indicate the vertical position to start printing this row, a `lineIncrement` used as a “leading” value for the text and lastly the `PrintPageEventArgs` variable `e` to draw the text to.

```
private void printRow(int rowIndex, float printX, float printY, float lineIncrement, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
  for (int col = 0; col < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; col++) {
    string text = dataGridView1[col, rowIndex].FormattedValue.ToString();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(printX, printY));
    printY += lineIncrement;
  }
}
```

Now that we have a method to print a single row from the `DatagridView` into a column in the print document, it should be easier to print the columns as rows and line the rows up. First as mentioned earlier, we need a global variable that keeps track of the `DataGridView`s row index while looping through it. This global variable `dgvRowIndex` is used each time the `PrintPage` method is called. I also added the font variable as a global variable.

```
// global variables 
int dgvRowIndex = 0;
Font font = new Font("Consolas", 13f);
```

Below is the `PrintPage` method to print each page. Most variable’s names are self-explanatory. `pageHeight` is used to determine when we need a new page. Two columns, `LeftColX` and `RightColX` are the two horizontal (X) starting points for each column. `curY` keeps track of the vertical (Y) position on the print page and is used to compare its value to `pageHeight` and start a new page if needed. `lineIncrement` is used as a “leading’ value for each new line. `spaceBefore` is used to add extra vertical space between the two printed rows. Lastly, as stated before, we need to keep track the vertical “Y” value when a new “column 1” is printed. `column2YValue` is used for this and is sent to the `PrintRow` method as the starting “Y” value when printing the second column.

When the while loop starts looping through the rows of the `DataGridView` , a check is made to see if this row is in column 1 or column 2. If `dgvRowIndex` is in column 1, then we need to save this starting “Y” `column2YValue` to use when printing the second column. If `dgvRowIndex` is in column2 then we simply call `printRow` method again, but this time we pass over the starting “Y” value from the previous column `column2YValue`. Extra vertical space is added, `dgvRowIndex` is incremented to go to the next row, then a check is made to see if we need to add another page. Here a simple check is made to see if the current “Y” value `curY` is past the margin, if it is, then we need to indicate a new page is needed then return. The `return` simply starts the `PrintPage` method over, this should work as expected since we now have a global variable `dgvRowIndex` to avoid starting at the beginning of the `DataGridView`. Hope this helps.

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
  float pageHeight = e.MarginBounds.Height;
  float leftColX = 10;
  float rightColX = 145;
  float curY = 10;
  float lineIncrement = 16;
  float spaceBefore = 24;
  float column2YValue = curY;
  while (dgvRowIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count) {
    if (dgvRowIndex % 2 == 0) {
      column2YValue = curY;
      printRow(dgvRowIndex, leftColX, curY, lineIncrement, e);
    } else {
      printRow(dgvRowIndex, rightColX, column2YValue, lineIncrement, e);
      curY += spaceBefore;
    }
    dgvRowIndex++;
    if (curY > pageHeight) {
      e.HasMorePages = true;
      return;
    }
    curY += spaceBefore;
  }
}
```

**Edit to address multiple columns and multiple rows.**

As I commented, in order to print multiple columns the code will need to keep track of the print “X” value on the page. The idea is to keep printing on the same (print) row (y value) until the “X” value goes past the right margin.

The other change addresses where to start the next print group/grid row. When the code calls `printRow` it is not known before that call how many columns the grid row may have. If the grid has three, four or 10 columns, then the code will print that number of lines. If there are 10 columns in each grid row… there will be 10 “print” rows for each row in the grid. Since `printRow` is going to loop through the columns to print, it is used to return this “next” “Y” print row value.

Tracing the code below, loops through the grids rows, first the current row is printed, and the next “print” row `nextRowYStart` is set based on how many columns are in the grid.

The next `if` statement checks if there is enough room on the right of the page to print another column. If there is enough room on the page for another column, then `curX` simply moves to the next column. If there is not enough room, the “X” value `curX` is reset to the left most (starting) column, `curY` is set to `nextRowYstart` to move down to the next print row, and some vertical space is added. A check is then made to see if the new print rows “Y” value  `curY` goes past the bottom margin. If it does, then we start a new page. Otherwise, simply print the next row of the grid.

The code assumes you want to print all the columns, however if you wanted to print only the first X columns, a `stopColumn` variable is added so you can decide how many of the first columns to print. I am guessing this may be what you are looking for. Hope it helps.

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
  //int stopColumn = 3;
  int stopColumn = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
  float pageHeight = e.MarginBounds.Height;
  float pageWidth = e.MarginBounds.Width;
  float startX = 50;
  float startY = 50;
  float columnWidth = 150;
  float curX = startX;
  float curY = startY;
  float lineIncrement = 16;
  float spaceBefore = 24;
  float nextRowYStart = curY;
  while (dgvRowIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count) {
    nextRowYStart = printRow(dgvRowIndex, curX, curY, lineIncrement, stopColumn, e);
    if (curX + columnWidth > pageWidth) {
      // start a new PRINT group/row
      curX = startX;    
      curY = nextRowYStart;
      curY += spaceBefore;
      if (curY > pageHeight + spaceBefore) {
        dgvRowIndex++;
        e.HasMorePages = true;
        return;
      }
    } else {
      curX += columnWidth;
    }
    dgvRowIndex++;
  }
}
```

Updated printRow method

```
private float printRow(int rowIndex, float printX, float printY, float lineIncrement, int stopCol, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
  for (int col = 0; col < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; col++) {
    if (col < stopCol) {
      string text = dataGridView1[col, rowIndex].FormattedValue.ToString();
      e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(printX, printY));
      printY += lineIncrement;
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return printY;
}
```

Comment: Hi `JohnG` thanks for your code this works good but when I am printing more number of columns these are over lapping can you tell me which values I should change.

Comment: I tried with binding the gridview with `Northwind` database and printing `1 to 9` columns instead of all

Comment: Hmmm… that will be different from what the original post describes. If this is the case then you will have to keep printing with the same “Y” value for each row until the “X” value gets too close to the right edge of the page. This will involve another variable that keeps track of the “X” value when printing.

Comment: Example: when each row is printed, before it is printed a check is needed to see if the “X” value plus the next column will be off the page on the right. If the ‘X” value plus the next column will not fit, then you move to the next row. From the code I posted, this column “shift” value appears to be around 150. Get the right hand margin with `float pageWidth = e.MarginBounds.Width;`, update the “X” value when a new column is printed and if “X” gets greater than the width then start a new row. I hope that make sense.

Comment: It should not be that difficult to make this change with the code I posted. Try something and if it does not work, post what you have tried and show what is not working.

Comment: Your first code works fine only problem when there is large text the right columns are getting overlapped. The only change I made is `float lineIncrement = 22;
            float spaceBefore = 45;`

Comment: Ok with these changes I am able to get the required output thanks `float rightColX = 345; float lineIncrement = 20;
            float spaceBefore = 70;`

Comment: Assuming each column is the same fixed width, the second (edited) code posted should address this with the `columnWidth` variable. Currently, the code adds (shifts right) this `columnWidth` amount for each new column. You should be able to adjust this value to prevent overlapping. Also the `spaceBefore` variable allows you to add extra "vertical" space between each printed group of rows.